# Pandas dataframe calculate number of journeys for each domain and number of urls in the journeys

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of the following format

```
    url                                     visitId      refId    timestamp
0   https://google.com/kindle               1            0        2019-03-08 07:01:40
1   https://google.com/                     2            1        2019-03-08 07:01:48
2   https://google.com/subscribe-and-save   3            2        2019-03-08 07:01:52
3   https://docs.google.com/abc             4            3        2019-03-08 07:02:23
4   https://youtube.com/music               5            4        2019-03-08 07:03:01
5   https://google.com/kindle               6            0        2019-03-08 07:08:00
6   https://example.com/                    7            0        2019-03-08 10:10:11
7   https://example.com/                    8            0        2019-03-08 10:11:00
8   https://example.com/                    9            8        2019-03-08 10:11:00
9   https://example.com/                    10           9        2019-03-08 10:11:00
```

Where `refId = 0`, means that the visit is a direct one, while non-zero values are the visitIds that refer to the url. The domain of the journey is the domain that is most frequent during the journey. Now this is one journey. The dataframe consists of several such journeys whose value I need to count in the number of such journeys and number of urls in the journey for each domain.

Expected Output of the dataframe above.

```
    Domain            Journey            Count
0   google.com        1                  5
1   example.com       1                  3
```

I have tackled this problem converting the pandas dataframe into a list of dictionaries as below.

```
df = [{'url':'https://google.com/kindle','visitId':1,'refId':0,'timestamp':datetime.datetime(2019,3,8,7,1,40)},
        {'url':'https://google.com/','visitId':2,'refId':1,'timestamp':datetime.datetime(2019,3,8,7,1,48)},
        {'url':'https://amazon.com/subscribe-and-save','visitId':3,'refId':2,'timestamp':datetime.datetime(2019,3,8,7,1,52)},
        {'url':'https://amazon.com/abc','visitId':4,'refId':3,'timestamp':datetime.datetime(2019,3,8,7,2,23)},
        {'url':'https://youtube.com/music','visitId':5,'refId':4,'timestamp':datetime.datetime(2019,3,8,7,3,1)},
        {'url':'https://amazon.com/kindle','visitId':6,'refId':0,'timestamp':datetime.datetime(2019,3,8,7,8,0)},
        {'url':'https://example.com/','visitId':7,'refId':0,'timestamp':datetime.datetime(2019,3,8,10,10,11)},
        {'url':'https://example.com/','visitId':8,'refId':0,'timestamp':datetime.datetime(2019,3,8,10,11,0)},
        {'url':'https://example.com/','visitId':9,'refId':8,'timestamp':datetime.datetime(2019,3,8,10,11,0)},
        {'url':'https://example.com/','visitId':10,'refId':9,'timestamp':datetime.datetime(2019,3,8,10,11,0)}]
```

Then I've used the following approach.

```
import datetime
import tldextract

def Journey():
    dat = [item for item in df if item['refId']!=0]

    dat = sorted(dat, key=lambda k: (k['timestamp']),reverse=True)

    repCheck = set()

    final = []
    count = 1

    visitIdToDocument = {}
    refIdToDocument = {}

    for item in df:
        visitIdToDocument[item['visitId']] = {'url':item['url'],'refId':item['refId']}

    for item in dat:
        refIdToDocument[item['refId']] = {'url':item['url'],'visitId':item['visitId']}

    for item in dat:
        lst = []
        rId = item['refId']
        flag = False
        try:
            vId = refIdToDocument[rId]['visitId']
            if vId not in repCheck:
                repCheck.add(vId)
                flag = True
        except KeyError: 
            pass
        repCheck2 = set()
        if flag:
            while True:
                if vId in repCheck2:
                    break
                else:
                    repCheck2.add(vId)
                try:
                    lst.append(visitIdToDocument[vId])
                    vId = rId
                    repCheck.add(vId)
                    rId = visitIdToDocument[vId]['refId']
                except KeyError:
                    if vId != '0' and vId != 0 and vId in visitIdToDocument:
                        lst.append(visitIdToDocument[vId])
                    break

            if len(lst) > 2:
                appendDict = {}
                journeyDomainLst = []
                jdla = ""
                for i in lst[::-1]:
                    jdla = "{}.{}".format((tldextract.extract(i['url'])).domain, (tldextract.extract(i['url'])).suffix)
                    if jdla[-1] == '.':
                        jdla = jdla[:-1]
                    journeyDomainLst.append(jdla)
                appendDict = {'Journey':1,'Domain':max(set(journeyDomainLst), key=journeyDomainLst.count),'Count':len(lst[::-1])}
                final.append(appendDict)
                count = count+1

    domains = {d['Domain'] for d in final}

    final=[{'Domain':dom, 'Journey': sum(d['Journey'] for d in final if d['Domain']==dom), 'Count': sum(d['Count'] for d in final if d['Domain']==dom)} for dom in domains]
    return final
```

Results in

```
[{'Domain': 'google.com', 'Journey': 1, 'Count': 5},
{'Domain': 'example.com', 'Journey': 1, 'Count': 3}]
```

Can the same results be achived using the pandas dataframe itself? And not use the list of dictionaries and other dictionaries created? If yes, then how do I go about it?

Comment: I have some questions, what is a "sub journey"? Something that did not start with 0? Or 0s starting on the same domain? Is your docs.google.com still google.com or a different domain and is this a new journey? I don't fully get it...

Comment: @anki - To answer both your questions  
1. What I've mentioned here is one complete journey. A sub-journey would be a subset of this journey e.g. - Just rows 0, 1 and 2. Need to filter for these duplicates, which I have in my code.  
2. docs.google.com would be part of the same journey. The domain/sub-domain doesn't matter. Only the linking visitIds and refIds. In the end, the domain (as evaluated using the tldextract module) with the maximum count in a journey, is the domain of the journey.

Comment: More questions: 1. Does a journey always start with refId=0 and end with a refId=0? 2. would the visitIds for the next journey continue from 7 or reset to 1? 3. Can a journey end abruptly?

Comment: @suicidalteddy - 1. No, 2. Continue, 3. Yes. I've modified the dataset in the question. Hope it helps!

Comment: I've also written a code for the same. Understanding that code, might help answer the questions. Let me know in the comments, in case there's a question around what's in the code.